# SQL subQuery in WHERE clause returns nothing

Tags: sql, oledb, visual-foxpro

I am doing this query with a subquery inside to the same table.

```
SELECT p.codigo_cl client_code, p.n_ordem proposal_id, p.data proposal_data, p.baumuster proposal_baumuster, p.vendedor proposal_seller_code, p.modelo proposal_model, p.preco_base proposal_base_price, p.preco_ext proposal_extras, p.ia proposal_ia, p.desconto proposal_discount
FROM proposta.DBF p 
INNER JOIN cliente.dbf c ON c.processo = p.codigo_cl 
WHERE p.N_ORDEM = (SELECT MAX(N_ORDEM) FROM proposta.DBF)
```

So the subquery is not returning the max value of the N_ORDEM and the result comes out empty.

I am using Microsft Visual Fox Pro OLEDB provider

The value returned from the subQuery is just to get the max value of the same table to use in the WHERE clause.

And then I make the data into a json format to post to my server

Comment: does `SELECT MAX(N_ORDEM) FROM proposta.DBF` on it's own give results?  have you tried `SELECT MAX(p2.N_ORDEM) FROM proposta.DBF p2`

Comment: Removing the [mysql] tag.

Comment: You should provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: Yes i tried `SELECT MAX(N_ORDEM) FROM proposta.DBF` and it returns the desired result. The max value of N_ORDEM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this work?

```
SELECT N_ORDEM
FROM proposta.DBF p 
WHERE p.N_ORDEM = (SELECT MAX(N_ORDEM) FROM proposta.DBF)
```

If it does, add back one feature a a time, eg the join.

```
SELECT N_ORDEM
FROM proposta.DBF p 
INNER JOIN cliente.dbf c ON c.processo = p.codigo_cl
WHERE p.N_ORDEM = (SELECT MAX(N_ORDEM) FROM proposta.DBF)
```

Comment: Well thank you for feedBack. By trying your code i discoverd that the problem was some inconsistency of the database. The INNER JOIN didn´t work beacuse of that. Thanks for the support

Answer (score 1):

You probably need a correlated subquery.  It is a little hard to guess exactly what you want, but an educated guess would be:

```
SELECT p.codigo_cl client_code, ...
FROM proposta.DBF p INNER JOIN
     cliente.dbf c
     ON c.processo = p.codigo_cl 
WHERE p.N_ORDEM = (SELECT MAX(p2.N_ORDEM)
                   FROM proposta.DBF p2
                   WHERE p2.codigo_cl = p.codigo_cl
                  );
```